# Should [facebook-yarn] and [yarnpkg] be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Both of these tags seem to refer to the newly released [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) package manager, and most questions seem to use both tags interchangeably.

There are 10 questions in [facebook-yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-yarn) and 16 questions in [yarnpkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg). 8 of these questions are tagged with both. [facebook-yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-yarn) also has fewer followers (5, compared to [yarnpkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg)'s 11). Therefore, it makes sense that [yarnpkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg) be the primary tag for these questions, with [facebook-yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-yarn) being a synonym.

[One question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40036481/how-could-yarnreplacement-for-npm-is-lightening-fast) used the tag [yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn), which is actually being used for a component of Apache Hadoop, though this doesn't seem to be a major problem.

Since there are very few questions about Yarn so far, this should be relatively pain-free, but it's definitely clear that these are tags about the exact same thing.

Comment: [tag:facebook-yarn] is no more